# How to check that user can write to JMS queue / topic?

Tags: queue, jms, rights

How is it possible to check that particular user has write rights to `Queue` / `Topic`, without affecting `Destination`.

If user has no such rights exception will be thrown and there would be zero-affection.

But if user has such rights, then new message will appear in `Queue` / `Topic`, and this is that shouldn't occur.

Is there any way to perform such test? May be is it possible to use transaction without commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think generally, it will depend on the JMS provider that you're using, as JMS itself does not specify security mechanisms. On IBM MQ, for example, calling `Session.createProducer(Destination queueOrTopic)` will throw an InvalidDestinationException if you're not authorized to send/publish messages to a destination.